# Scala Option and Some mismatch

Tags: scala, apache-flink

I want to parse province to case class, it throws mismatch

scala.MatchError: Some(USA) (of class scala.Some)

```
  val result = EntityUtils.toString(entity,"UTF-8")
  val address = JsonParser.parse(result).extract[Address]

  val value.province = Option(address.province)
  val value.city = Option(address.city)
```

```
case class Access(
                    device: String,
                    deviceType: String,
                    os: String,
                    event: String,
                    net: String,
                    channel: String,
                    uid: String,
                    nu: Int,
                    ip: String,
                    time: Long,
                    version: String,
                    province: Option[String],
                    city: Option[String],
                    product: Option[Product]
                  )
```

Comment: I had to do a lot of guessing (like e.g. what is the type of `value`), could you reword the question to make it clearer?

Comment: First of all,  these operators occur in a map function. So the value is the mapper's input, type is Access.

Comment: I am parsing a Json to case class using Json4s. Things are going complicated, I need to parse the json first to clean the data. The province and city are later got from ip analysis. I want to parse them during the second parsing.  It occurs a mismatch, and copy might be a way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```scala
val value.province = Option(address.province)
val value.city = Option(address.city)
```

doesn't do what you think it does. It tries to treat `value.province` and `value.city` as [extractors](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/extractor-objects.html) (which don't match the type, thus `scala.MatchError` exception). It doesn't mutate `value` as I believe you intended (because `value` apparently doesn't have such setters).

Since `value` is (apparently) `Access` case class, it is immutable and you can only obtain an updated copy:

```
val value2 = value.copy(
  province = Option(address.province),
  city     = Option(address.city)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the starting point:

```scala
val province: Option[String] = ???
```

You can get the string with simple pattern matching:

```scala
province match {
  case Some(stringValue) => JsonParser.parse(stringValue).extract[Province] //use parser to go from string to a case class
  case None => .. //maybe provide a default value, depends on your context
}
```

Note: Without knowing what `extract[T]` returns it's hard to recommend a follow-up